Shortest path through vertex in weighted graph (Proof)
I'm currently studying several classic graph algorithms for shortest paths (Dijkstra, Bellman-Ford, etc.) and came to the following problem:
Problem
We have $G:=(V,E,\omega)$, a weighted, connected, directed graph, i.e. there's and edge $(V_i,V_j)$ from every $V_i$ to every $V_j$, $i\neq j$, with non-negative weights $\omega((V_i,V_j))$
We select an arbitrary vertex $V_P$ to be our "pivot" vertex. We now want to find out the shortest path from $V_i$ to $V_j$, passing through our pivot vertex, $\delta_{V_P}(V_i,V_j)$ for some $i\neq j$.
Solution
In the solution of the problem, it is stated that to do this, one just finds the shortest path between $V_i$ and $V_P$ and then from $V_P$ to $V_j$, or in other words:
$$
\delta_{V_P}(V_i, V_j) = \delta(V_i,V_P) + \delta(V_P,V_j)
$$
Proof
No proof was offered. And although this certainly seems plausible and intuitive, it is not trivially unambiguous for me. I would therefore be very happy if I could have some help proving this.
My first idea was to state the case that there exist a different shortest path that is different, and then arrive at a contradiction or that it can only be true if its the same one.

Suppose $a + b< c+d$, where $a$, $b$ are the two lengths in a hypothetical shorter path and $c$, $d$ are the two paths in the given solution.  We cannot have ($a \geq c$ and $b \geq d$) otherwise $a+b \geq c+d$, a contradiction.  Therefore either $a < c$ or $b < d$, but $c$ was minimal of paths from $V_i$ to $V_P$, so $a \geq c$ and likewise for $b$...

@EricTowers Beautiful. If you want to write it as an answer I'd upvote it and select as official answer. Otherwise I'll select the current answer.

To show $\delta_{V_P}(V_i, V_j) \le \delta(V_i,V_P) + \delta(V_P,V_j)$: Let $p_1$ be a shortest path from $V_i$ to $V_P$, and $p_2$ a shortest path from $V_P$ to $V_j$. Then their concatenation $p_1 p_2$ is a path from $V_i$ to $V_j$ passing through $V_P$, so
$$\delta_{V_P}(V_i, V_j) \le l(p_1 p_2) = l(p_1) + l(p_2) = \delta(V_i,V_P) + \delta(V_P,V_j).$$
To show $\delta_{V_P}(V_i, V_j) \ge \delta(V_i,V_P) + \delta(V_P,V_j)$: Let $p$ be shortest among paths from $V_i$ to $V_j$ which pass through $V_P$. Split it into two segments $p = p_1 p_2$, where $p_1$ goes from $V_i$ to $V_P$, and $p_2$ from $V_P$ to $V_j$. Then $l(p_1) \ge \delta(V_i,V_P)$ and $l_2 \ge \delta(V_P,V_j)$, so
$$\delta_{V_P}(V_i, V_j) = l(p_1 p_2) = l(p_1) + l(p_2) \ge \delta(V_i,V_P) + \delta(V_P,V_j).$$
(Assumed notation: $\delta(V_i, V_j)$ is the minimum length of a path from $V_i$ to $V_j$, and $\delta_{V_P}(V_i, V_j)$ is the minimum length of a path from $V_i$ to $V_j$ which passes through $V_P$. I assume the graph is finite so that the minimum is defined. The length of a path $p$ is $l(p)$.)
